# Why are contains and add confusing each other?

Tags: java, addition, contains

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
/**
 *
 * @author user
 */
public class Exercise1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        int numOfLines = 0;
        int numOfWords = 0;

        Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(new File("C:/Users/user/Downloads/exercise.txt"));
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        int[] arr = new int[1000];
        while (scan1.hasNextLine()) {
            String s = scan1.nextLine();
            for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
                if (!Character.isAlphabetic(s.charAt(i))) {
                } else {
                    //is an alphabet
                    int j = i; //stop index;
                    //find the complete word
                    while (Character.isAlphabetic(s.charAt(j))) {
                        j++;
                        if (j == s.length()) {
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    i = j; //set to last index
                    //check if list has the string
                    if (list.contains(s.substring(i, j))) {
                        list.add(s.substring(i, j));
                        System.out.println(list.size());
                        arr[list.indexOf(s.substring(i, j))]++;
                    } else {
                        arr[list.indexOf(s.substring(i, j))]++;
                    }
                    numOfWords++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list.toArray()));
        System.out.println(numOfWords);
    }
}
```

I was trying to retrieve text from a text file containing letters, numbers and special characters but the **contains** method and **add** method seem to be confusing each other.

When a string of word is found, I made the code to work by checking if the string of word is contained in the ArrayList, if it is so, the index of the particular string will be used as point for increment in another array (to record the number of words).

But when I run the code an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException exception is thrown, meaning that the index obtained is -1 (this will happen if the string is not found and the ArrayList will implicitly return -1), but when I tried to test the existence of the string in the ArrayList the result is **true**, indicating that the ArrayList has the certain string but still return -1 when called for the string's index. Please help, thanks a lot!

Comment: *indicating that the ArrayList has the certain string but still return -1* - are you 100% sure? It seems to me that the error could be with `arr[list.indexOf(s.substring(i, j))]++;` for two reasons: 1) in the `if` block, `list.indexOf` could return a number bigger than the size of `arr`. 2) in the `else` block you call `list.indexOf` but `list.contains` just returned `false` (so the result will obviously be -1). Both ways would generate an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, you should include the full stack trace and point us to the line it's referring to.

Comment: when I added an exclamation mark in front of "list.contains(s.substring(i, j))" the output will be an empty ArrayList with a size of 1.

Comment: I don't think it's possible for the list to return an index larger than the array size because the total number of words in the text file is less than half of the array size (100).

Comment: Don't *think*: **debug** :) And update the question with the full stack trace, please.

Comment: Not sure how to debug haha, is compiling the code equal debugging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because you are trying to find an index of a string which is not present in the list. To resolve this, you should be adding `!` before `list.contains(s.substring(i, j))`

After you add this, your code compiles and run but you get an empty array. This happens because of line `i = j;`.

**Why ?** Because initially you are doing `int j = i;`, then your logic to find the word length if it is alphabetic, doing `j++` and then once you have the length, you do `i = j;`. So basicially what happens in `i` and `j` will always have same value. So when you do substring, noting gets returned, because `i` and `j` are same. `Try commenting this line  i = j;` and you should see output. I advise you to change your logic a little to find word and add it to list